# Is it possible to make generic method signature implementing generic + interface?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to use generics something like that in Java 1.7?

```
class Test<T> {
    public <Z extends T & Serializable> void method(Z test) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I would like my method to accept only objects of generic type  which implements specific interface.

Comment: No `implements` in type bounds. It's always `extends`

Comment: I know, i wrote code with extends, just made example incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately it is not possible to use generic `extends` with a generic type and an interface. In fact, it is not even possible to use generic `extends` with multiple types. If you could, then you could do something like the following.

```
class Test<T, B extends Serializable> {

    public <Z extends T & B> void method(Z test) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This restriction against extending multiple types may be because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At runtime the generics are removed and `public <Z extends Serializable>` simply becomes `public Serializable`. So what would `<Z extends T & Serializable>` be replaced with?

Answer (score 1):

The most approximated form would be:

```
class Test<T extends Serializable>
{
    public <Z extends T> void method(Z test)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the case, class generic can't use this interface it should be specific for method only.